# Can't create data rails, no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm implementing a website using Ruby on Rails. I have a trouble which I cannot create a new data and save to my model. The error i got is this which the error pointed to the @vpermits = current_user.vpermits.build(vpermit_params). Anyone have idea on what I have i done wrong?

```
NoMethodError in VisitorPermitsController#create
undefined method `vpermits' for #<User:0x9b7b478>


    def create
        @vpermits = current_user.vpermits.build(vpermit_params)
        if @vpermits.save
          redirect_to @vpermits
        else
```

This is my visitor_permits_controller.rb

```
class VisitorPermitsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_vpermit, only: [:destroy]
    def index
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end

    def new
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.new
    end

    def create
        @vpermits = current_user.vpermits.build(vpermit_params)
        if @vpermits.save
          redirect_to @vpermits
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end


    def destroy
      VisitorPermit.destroy_all(user_id: current_user)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Permit was successfully canceled.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    def show
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.where(user_id: current_user).take
      respond_to do |format|
        if @vpermits.update(vpermit_params)
          format.html { redirect_to root_path}
          flash[:success] = "Permit successfully updated"
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    def edit
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:id])
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_vpermit
      @vpermits = VisitorPermit.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def vpermit_params
      params.require(:visitor_permit).permit(:vehicle_type, :name, :department, :carplate, :duration, :permitstart, :permitend)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Does your user have `has_many :vpermits`? How does your user model look like? How does your user database table look like?

Comment: Ahhh, i found my problem already. The problem is that i was using vpermits which my has_many is visitor_permits. Now I have changed it, thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

From your code you might have association(has_many) between  `User` and `VistorPermit` models. And you gave your model name as `VistorPermit`. So the 
line of code for buliding should be like this:

```
@vpermits = current_user.vistor_permits.build(vpermit_params)
```

Comment: Yep that's the solution